# 301 redirect old site to new maintaining some folder structure but not all

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I'm in the process of "moving" my site from a subdomain to a subfolder on the root domain, and in the process have to change some of the subdirectory structure as a matter of cause. This has made redirecting a little difficult for someone with as little htaccess knowledge as I do.

Some of the structure will be the same for things deeper in the architecture (it's essentially a directory website) but some things will need to move. Below is what I have created thus far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/for-sale$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/search$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/for-sale-details$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/details$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/buyer-registration
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/buyer-registration [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/advertise-with-us
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/advertise-with-us [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/favourites
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/favourites [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/saved-searches
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/saved-searches [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/system$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/system$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/ [R=301,L]
```

An example of what I want to happen is for

```
http://subdomain.example.com/for-sale-details/35141_xml_bvi0009154/gensac-gironde
```

to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/property-for-sale/details/35141_xml_bvi0009154/gensac-gironde
```

and so on.

Essentially, the above redirects without $ at the end of the code are standalone pages, and there are no further subdirectories after that. Anything with the $ at the end means there is further layers of directory, but anything after that should be preserved at the end of the new URL.

Any help would be very much appreciated! And yes, I'm a complete noob when it comes to this kind of thing, so please be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` var is the "Host" header from the request, which **only** contains the hostname, and no path info like `/for-sale`. Thus you match only against that and none of your rules will work because you're attempting to match against the URI path.

So instead, all of your rules need to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^for-sale/(.*)$ /property-for-sale/search/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^for-sale-details/(.*)$ /property-for-sale/details/$1 [R=301,L]
```

etc.